# Git throws a "Permission Denied" error when trying to push files

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh, error-handling

I'm working on Windows CMD and that's it, Git is throwing error:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

when I'm trying to push my folder into the repository via CMD.

- When I execute a `ssh -vT git@github.com` or `ssh -T git@github.com` it works perfectly
- When I execute `git push origin master`, the problem occurs that indicates like I'm not registered
- When I try to do it via `git-bash`, it throws the same error, like it is not detecting my `/.ssh/` folder

I tried to add the SSH keys in the `git-bash` with "`ssh-add %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\keyname`" it is perfectly added, I can then perform "`git push origin master`" from the `git-bash` and it works.

The problem is that when I close the console it "restarts" that key added before. I think something similar happens when I perform the push from the CMD, its like that a new "git environment" is created and it does not have the keys that Windows have saved.

I think that the error resides on the key name, that is "gh-key" and "gh-key.pub" respectively. It works fine by using "id_rsa" but I do not want to use that name, I think just git-bash is not recognizing it when is other name.

Thanks everyone and sorry about my poor English.

Comment: If you don't want to use the default name for the keys you might have to set up the ssh config file. https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/. Try `Host *` and set `IdentityFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the SSH agent not automatically loading your custom-named SSH key when starting a new session. By default, the SSH agent looks for a key named `id_rsa`.

To solve this, you can create a config file in your `~/.ssh` directory to tell the SSH agent to also look for your custom-named key.
If you don;t have a config file yet, simply create a file named `config` in `~/.ssh` directory, and add the following lines into the file:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh-key
```

Make sure you save the ghanges!
Now, the SSH agent should automatically load your gh-key whenever you start a new session. Try running git push origin master again in a new Git Bash or CMD session to see if the issue is resolved.